# Installing Fedora on new HD

Tags: fedora, system-installation, dual-boot, hard-disk

Right now I'm dual booted with Win 10 and Ubuntu on a single HD. I bought a second HD and want to install Fedora on it much the same as a dual boot, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. Does the fact that this is a clean disk change anything?

When I originally installed Ubuntu, I used the automatic option which installed GRUB and took care of all the partitioning for me. Is there a similar option for Fedora? Is it best to do everything manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can install Fedora on the second HD, and during installation select your first HD as the boot device. Fedora will update GRUB.
See : https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning.html

Comment: Would that mean that Fedora couldn't boot without the first disk since that's where GRUB is?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the disk where grub is installed you can't boot anymore.

Comment: Is there a way around that? I suppose I could install Fedora stand-alone on the second disk and just choose the correct HD from the BIOS, but hat loses some convenience. Is there anyway to keep a single GRUB menu, yet have an independent install?

Comment: You could install grub on both disk (after the installation). And in the BIOS select which disk you want to boot from.

Comment: There is a way to add linux (and others) to Windows' bootloader, effectively chainloading grub from there. As to how it's done, you'll have to do some searching, since I don't know the specifics.